# Pegar a hora do banco sql server formatada

Tags: sql, sql-server

O meu banco de dados tem uma diferença de 4 horas, o suporte até o momento não deu uma solução, então eu gostaria de saber como eu posso formatar a saída da hora:

```
select 
CAST(HORA_FECHAMENTO AS datetime) as HORA_FECHAMENTO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(05), DATEADD(hour, +4, getdate()), 108) AS 'HORA'
from TB_ESTRACAO 
where ID > 0
```

Saída:

```
1900-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 15:29
```

Preciso que seja assim:

```
11:00 | 15:29
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só o sinal de `+` que não precisa. O resto está certo.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(HORA_FECHAMENTO AS datetime), 108) as HORA_FECHAMENTO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(hour, 4, getdate()), 108) AS 'HORA'
from TB_ESTRACAO 
where ID > 0
```

Comment: A sua resposta não está correta

Comment: eu preciso da saida da informação formatada, você apenas tirou o sinal de +?

Comment: Ah, entendi. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Acho que houve um problema de comunicação, porque eu não quero concatenação  a hora,

Comment: ajuste a pergunta

Comment: Verdade. Veja agora.